# LibreOffice Calc: Add trendline - compute minimum

Tags: libreoffice

I have a set of points (the blue ones). I want to add a trend line (like the green one - which is added by hand) and compute the minimal x value of the trend line (in this case the minimum is around 45,0.93)

[image: Pointset with trendgraph]

How do I do that? The trend line I found in LibreCalc does not seem to be able to do a bezier.

Comment: Is this a problem because you want a trend line that is not a function of x? Swapping the variables may be a good idea then.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski If you want to swap x/y it is fine.